# Question regarding singular plural verbs

Tags: singular-vs-plural

One of the things we see every day **are/is** these abandoned houses right here.

One thing we need **are/is** books.

Are both **are** and **is** applicable here?

Answer (score 1):

> One of the things we see every day are/is these abandoned houses right
> here.

You will find many arguments on language forums about whether singular or plural should be used in this situation.

Some say *"One ... is ... these houses.*

Others say *"things ... are ... these houses"*

Personally I wouldn't write it that way - I don't like that sort of sentence.

---

> One thing we need are/is books.

You will find people arguing about this too. However I strongly advocate using "is" in this situation. The subject of the sentence is undeniably singular and that is what determines the verb.

"One thing ... is books"